# boost-spirit-lex multi-valued token_def<>

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, lexer

Is it possible to wire up a `token_def<>` and it's associated regular expression so it can parse a token with multiple values within it ? For example `1234:hello_world`. Where `1234` and `hello_world`. Or should I be doing this sort of thing in a `qi::rule` ?

I'm very mutch thinking the answer will be that tokens should be atomic and even if there was a way to do it, it would be inadvisable :D

Comment: I don't know enough about Spirit Lex to give an answer, but your description reminded me of [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/example/lex/custom_token_attribute.cpp). If you want to do something similar you will need to define your token as, for example, `token_def<std::pair<int,std::string> >` and then partially specialize `template <typename Iter> struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<std::pair<int,std::string>, Iter>` in namespace `boost::spirit::traits`. Inside the `call` function member you get iterators to the original string and you can use `qi::parse`.

Comment: What @cv_and_he said. And I second your own analysis. Why would you feel you "need" this?

Comment: My question stemms from misunderstanding the lexer -> parser relationship (hmm did a vote to close and comment to close ended up here).